# How can I make a QThread sleep for 1 second (using PyQt)?

Tags: python, plot, timer, pyqt, qthread

I've been working in an application with PyQt where I analyze incoming video from a camera and generate a plot using dummy values once the user clicks a "start button". Both the camera and the graph run in two different QThreads and they currently work as expected, however, when I click the start button, the following message appears in my terminal each time the plot is generated: "QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread".

Since the camera section is working fine, I'll leave that out of the following code to simplify the issue, only the second Thread (the one in charge of plotting dummy data) is left. This is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import time

# # # # # MAIN GUI CLASS DEFINITION # # # # #
class main_GUI(QMainWindow):
    p1 = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\BRAIN\MCE\Acquisition_System\GUI_Qt.ui", self)
        self.btn_deactivate.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_activate.clicked.connect(self.activar)
        self.btn_deactivate.clicked.connect(self.desactivar)
        self.Worker2 = Worker2()
        empaticaConstructor = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.empatica_graph.addWidget(empaticaConstructor) 
        main_GUI.p1 = empaticaConstructor.addPlot (title = "probando")

    def activar(self):
        self.btn_deactivate.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_activate.setEnabled(False)
        self.state.setText("Activado")
        self.Worker2.start()

    def desactivar(self):
        self.btn_deactivate.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_activate.setEnabled(True)
        self.state.setText("Desactivado")
        self.Worker2.terminate()

# # # # # CLASSES FOR ADDED WIDGETS # # # # #
class Worker2(QThread):
    x = None
    y = None

    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        while self.ThreadActive:
            Worker2.x = np.random.normal(size=50)
            Worker2.y = np.random.normal(size=50)
            main_GUI.p1.plot(Worker2.x, Worker2.y, pen=None, symbol='o')
            time.sleep(2)

# # # # # INITIATE EXECUTION OF APP # # # # #
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = main_GUI()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried to read similar posts and the documentation, I believe the problem has to do with using a timer inside the Thread (because I read it has its own sort of timer) and so I tried to use a QTimer but I've had no success at all. Any help is appreciated.

I also attach an image of the problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1WRj.jpg)

Comment: You can't do UI from a secondary thread.  That's true of every GUI framework.  In your case, you don't need a thread.  Just create a timer that fires every 2 seconds and do your plotting from there.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the response. The app is supposed to display two graphs that receive data from two different devices, as well as display the video from the camera. This is why I implemented a thread. Given that these devices are I/O bound according to what I investigated, it is necessary to heave threads, or else the whole GUI would freeze. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Gustavo_OL Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread. So you cannot create or update the plots within the worker thread. All you can do is generate the data in the worker, send it to the main thread (using custom signals), and then update the plots from there. Whatever data you send must be pickleable.

Comment: If your devices are blocking devices, you can certainly have a thread dedicated to reading from the devices and processing the data,, but you will have to `emit` an event to send the data into the main window for display.  The GUI activities all have to be done in the main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much both @ekhumoro and Tim Roberts (seems I can only notify one user per comment). Both responses made me understand how I must structure the data acquisition for it to work properly and then be plotted. Happy Christmas!